# Apache Cordova: How to Auto-reload the app during development when changes detected?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Good day, everyone. I am using latest Cordova build with latest recommended NPM and was wondering if there is a faster way to assess changes made to the app's code than to CTRL+C out of the app and run **cordova run browser** as it takes a while to load when testing rapid changes.

There's a bunch of plugins like *--livereload* and *browser sync* which do not seem to want to install or run due to depreciated code, dependencies, or just being abandoned for years.

What can I use today to get an app to reload in real time in the browser as I push changes to the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question since I was searching for an answer. Here's the solution I came up with.

I created a script to watch the `www` directory for changes and restart cordova when it changes.

```bash
while [ 1 ]
do
    cordova run browser &
    cordova_pid=$!
    inotifywait -e create -e modify -r --exclude ".+.swp" www
    kill $cordova_pid
done
```

Modify as needed.
`$!` gets the process id of the last comment, the cordova process.

inotifywait will watch the www directory for any new files added or modified within the directory. The command runs until you ctrl + c or a change is detected. Exclude watching any files created by your editor.

Once the change is detected, it will kill the cordova process and start a new one.

Now any time you make a change to a file the cordova process will automatically restart.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can and should create a vhost and host your `www` folder (via Apache, IIS etc).
Add something like this to your host file

```
 127.0.0.1     my.app
```

Then access your app via `http://my.app`

Then just hit F5 when you make changes

Comment: That is what I am doing right now but I don't think that updates the instance of the Cordova application running from the terminal. That just allows me to see the updates html, css and js code. What about all the Cordova API related code like file transfer and local file storage code?

Comment: There is no rapid test path with native interfacing (cordova). You either do what you do or build a test build and test on device or emulator...